# Install the iOS app via Xcode gives old transaction

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When I reinstall the app with my subscription secret unchanged ,

```
   let receiptFileURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL
                let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptFileURL!)
                let receiptBase64String = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                guard let stringReceipt = receiptBase64String else { return }
```

Above section of code gives me the old and expired response before installing the new version. I swear whether I have logged in my sandbox account or not, the result gives me the response

```
 transaction_id : 1000000558259116
 original_transaction_id : 1000000558239264
 productId : YP20190527_3
renewalDict : {
    "auto_renew_product_id" = "YP20190527_3";
    "auto_renew_status" = 0;
    "expiration_intent" = 1;
    "is_in_billing_retry_period" = 0;
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000558239264;
    "product_id" = "YP20190527_3";
}
```

What should I do next if I want to simulate a completely new iPhone and proceed purchases? I guess this old response force me prompting the Apple sandbox login for all time

Updates: When I try to ping   sandbox.itunes.apple.com  , it gives 100% packet loss. When I login my sandbox account at iTunes and App Store Section of my iPhone setting , I cannot login even I have got correct password and email.

Still, the system status of Apple gives available service of Sandbox iTunes User? I am not sure whether my in-app subscription can be tested using sandbox account

https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

[image]

While visiting this link with browser, it say Service unavailable  [image]

Could you please tell us when I can test the in-app subscription now ?

Comment: You should log out from your Sandbox account on iPhone. Go to Settings -> iTunes & App Stores -> at the bottom your sandbox account -> Log out. If you want to test a new account, you should create a new sandbox user at your App Store Connect -> Users and Access -> Sandbox Users section. I am the owner of this blog. Feel free to contact me. More details about testing here: https://blog.apphud.com/swift-tutorial-subscriptions/

Comment: Have you tried with a brand new sandbox user as well?

Comment: I resort to using new iphone to test